# Scaling view on orientation change for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Initially my application supported only landscape mode. Now I want it to support Portrait mode too and in Portrait mode display scaled down version of landscape mode. How can I do that? I have tried to use transform property and scale it with 2/3 multiplier but for some reason result is not in the center of the screen. I think this should be standard task but I can't find any examples, information on this.

Best Regards, Aleksey

Comment: Are you using UIKit for your interface?

Comment: Yes I am using UIKit and I create all the elements manually(without use of Interface Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the view.center property after you scale it?

Something like this:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.67, 0.67);
view.center = CGPointMake(160, 240); //or wherever you want it
```

Also, keep in mind that if you are doing other transformations (rotate, translate) at the same time then order matters.  So you would most likely want to rotate first, then scale, then translate.

Comment: I have tried this and was able to position scaled view correctly on screen , but for some reason buttons stopped to work for me. May be this solution was incorrect in first place and I should try something different?